# How do I use Vimeo oEmbed API in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am working on a react web application that can upload videos to Vimeo and retrieve them when required. I am able to successfully upload the video privately. I am using the hide from Vimeo privacy setting and embed on specific domains option. On uploading the video I want to receive an embeddable iframe string from the backend server so that I can display the video in my react app.
The oEmbed API provided on Vimeo API reference page is working in postman. But when I try to get it  through nodejs string I get the following error:

> Error: {"error":"The requested page couldn't be found."}
> at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\prith\node_modules\vimeo\lib\vimeo.js:164:19)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) status code 404 headers {
> connection: 'close',   'content-length': '49',   server: 'nginx',
> 'content-type': 'application/vnd.vimeo.error+json',   expires: 'Sun,
> 10 Apr 2022 20:00:04 GMT',   'cache-control': 'private, no-store,
> no-cache',   'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000;
> includeSubDomains; preload',   'request-hash': '8fa895fc',
> 'x-bapp-server': 'api-v22576-6dhrr',   'x-vimeo-dc': 'ge',
> 'accept-ranges': 'bytes',   via: '1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish',
> 'fastly-original-body-size': '0',   date: 'Mon, 11 Apr 2022 08:00:04
> GMT',   'x-served-by': 'cache-iad-kiad7000087-IAD,
> cache-maa10229-MAA',   'x-cache': 'MISS, MISS',   'x-cache-hits': '0,
> 0',   'x-timer': 'S1649664004.146166,VS0,VE292',   vary:
> 'Accept,Vimeo-Client-Id' }

This is my code:

**vimeo_embed.js**

```
let Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;

const USER_ID = "USER_ID"
const USER_SECRET = "USER_SECRET"
const USER_TOKEN = "USER_TOKEN"

let client = new Vimeo(USER_ID, USER_SECRET, USER_TOKEN);

client.request({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/app/oembed.json/',
    query: {url: 'https%3A//vimeo.com/xxxxxxxx'}
},function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('body');
      console.log(body);
    }
   
    console.log('status code');
    console.log(status_code);
    console.log('headers');
    console.log(headers);
  });
```

I am not clear about why this error is thrown. I have verified that the authentiction is working.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the NodeJS lib does not have oembed endpoint yet, as you can see here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference#table-1

So you need to use old way to fetch this data.